# Get multiple images as background

Tags: wordpress-theming

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to **implement multiple backgrounds** (for a slider) into my header.

I already done all the customizer work and i am now trying to set things up so i can just let a bit of javascript circle trough the different background images that i set up.

**Header home page code (header-home.php) :**

```
<header class="site-header">
<div class="row header-home" <?php
if ((get_theme_mod('slider_radio', 'slider') == 'static')) {
    echo 'style="background-image:url(' . get_header_image() . ');' . 'background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center; background-size: cover;min-height:100vh">';
} else {
    echo 'style="background-image:url(' .
        getsliderimage1() . ',url(\'' .
        getsliderimage2() . ',url(\'' .
        getsliderimage3() . ');' .
        'background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center; background-size: cover;min-height:100vh">';
} ?>
<?php get_template_part('template-parts/header/site', 'branding'); ?>
<?php get_template_part('template-parts/header/menu', 'top'); ?>
</div>
```

**slider.php code that it refers to**

```
function getsliderimage1()
{
    if (!empty(get_theme_mod('slider_image_1'))) {
        echo get_theme_mod('slider_image_1', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/image1.jpg') . ')';
    }
}

function getsliderimage2()
{
    if (!empty(get_theme_mod('slider_image_2'))) {
        echo get_theme_mod('slider_image_2', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/image1.jpg') . ')';
    }
}

function getsliderimage3()
{
    if (!empty(get_theme_mod('slider_image_3'))) {
        echo get_theme_mod('slider_image_3', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/image1.jpg') . ')';
    }
}
```

**My problem is that when i turn on my slider_radio to not 'static' that the slider.php gets loaded and it just breaks my page from where it is loaded.**

Obviously i made a mistake somewhere. I just can not pin point where. Been searching for hours now.

Hoping someone of you can tell me what i'm doing wrong.

New to wordpress theme development here.

Thanks already!

**Edit :**

Let me explain a little further. My intention is to only add the image background to the backgrounds when it is used in the customizer. The 3 controls that contain these images (or not if not used) is slider_image_1 , slider_image_2 and slider_image_3

**UPDATE:**

It seems when i paste my function directly in the same fille it has no problems loading the page anymore. Hmmn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A whole lot of testing and coding later i got it to work with just converting everything into the same file with some adjustments.

When u use echo for the links and use them to past into another echo the slashes get deleted. U can solve this by using an echo for each part of the code without functions :

Like this :

```
<header class="site-header">
    <div class="row header-home" <?php
    if ((get_theme_mod('slider_radio', 'slider') == 'static')) {
        echo 'style="background-image:url(' . get_header_image() . ');' . 'background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center; background-size: cover;min-height:100vh">';
    } else {
        echo 'style="background-image:';
        if (!empty(get_theme_mod('slider_image_1', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/image1.jpg'))) {
            echo 'url(' . esc_url(get_theme_mod('slider_image_1', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/image1.jpg'))
                . ')';
            if (!empty(get_theme_mod('slider_image_2', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/image1.jpg')) || !empty(get_theme_mod('slider_image_3', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/image1.jpg')))
            {
                echo ',';
            }
        }
        if (!empty(get_theme_mod('slider_image_2', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/image1.jpg'))) {
            echo 'url(' . esc_url(get_theme_mod('slider_image_2', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/image1.jpg')) . ')';
            if (!empty(get_theme_mod('slider_image_3', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/image1.jpg')))
            {
                echo ',';
            }
        }
        if (!empty(get_theme_mod('slider_image_3', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/image1.jpg'))) {
            echo 'url(' . esc_url(get_theme_mod('slider_image_3', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/image1.jpg')) . ')';
        }
        echo ';';
        echo 'background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center; background-size: cover;min-height:100vh">';
    } ?>
    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/header/site', 'branding'); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/header/menu', 'top'); ?>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

**If u use bootstrap then this works better :**

```
<header class="site-header">
    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/header/site', 'branding'); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/header/menu', 'top'); ?>
    <div class="row header-home" <?php
    if ((get_theme_mod('slider_radio', 'slider') == 'static')) {
        echo 'style="background-image:url(' . get_header_image() . ');' . 'background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center; background-size: cover;min-height:100vh">';
    } else {
    echo '>';
    ?>
    <script>$('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 2000
        })
    </script>
    <div id="designitCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#designitCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#designitCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#designitCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <?php
            if (!empty(get_theme_mod('slider_image_1', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/image1.jpg'))) {
                echo '<div class="item active"><img src="';
                echo esc_url(get_theme_mod('slider_image_1', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/image1.jpg')) . '"';
                echo 'alt="Image 1">';
                echo '<div class="carousel-caption">';
                echo '<h1>' . get_theme_mod('slider_text_1') . '</h1>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
            if (!empty(get_theme_mod('slider_image_2', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/image1.jpg'))) {
                echo '<div class="item"><img src="';
                echo esc_url(get_theme_mod('slider_image_2', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/image1.jpg')) . '"';
                echo 'alt="Image 2">';
                echo '<div class="carousel-caption">';
                echo '<h1>' . get_theme_mod('slider_text_2') . '</h1>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
            if (!empty(get_theme_mod('slider_image_3', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/image1.jpg'))) {
                echo '<div class="item"><img src="';
                echo esc_url(get_theme_mod('slider_image_3', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/image1.jpg')) . '"';
                echo 'alt="Image 3">';
                echo '<div class="carousel-caption">';
                echo '<div class="slide-text slide_style_left">';
                echo '<h1 data-animation="animated zoomInRight">' . get_theme_mod('slider_text_3') . '</h1>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
            ?>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#designitCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#designitCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php
        } ?>
    </div>
</header>
```

**Extra css :**

```
.header-home {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
#designitCarousel {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -5;
    position: absolute;
}
#designitCarousel img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.carousel-inner {
max-height: 100vh;
}
.carousel-inner > .item {
    max-height: 100vh;
}
.carousel-caption {
    padding-bottom: 25%;
}
```